# PHP cURL request takes up the entire Timeout

Tags: php, laravel, curl, laravel-5

I currently have a Laravel application, which is doing a CURL request from one route to another route within the same route. My CURL looks like this:

```
//LOGGING THAT A CURL CALL IS ABOUT TO BE MADE 
$url = env('APP_URL') . '/tests/add/results'; 
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); //return server error
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $test_post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

In the route, that the POST is being sent to, the first thing i log, is the request data:

```
//LOGING THAT I RECEIVED THE CURL CALL in receiving function
```

I'm noticing, that the logs for the request data get logged exactly the same amount of time as the timeout, meaning the request is actually being sent 10 seconds after the initial call.

In my logs i'll see something like:

```
10:10:10 - LOGGING CURL CALL
10:10:20 - Recieving CURL call
```

If i change the timeout to 30, then the log shows 30 seconds later that i received the CURL call.

Does anyone have any idea why this may be happening?

The response from the CURL just comes back as `false` always.

Comment: What exactly returns the `env('APP_URL')` ?

Comment: its the URL to my app on localhost which is http://127.0.0.1:8000

Comment: what happens if you curl the url from the command line?

Comment: From postman it works fine

Comment: Did you ever find the cause of this?

Comment: Yes will put it as answer so you see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did the following to make a post request work:
Instead of calling the route via CURL i did a post directly to the route function

```
            $testController = new TestsController;
            $test_data_request = new \Illuminate\Http\Request();
            $test_data_request->setMethod('POST');
            $test_data_request->request->add( $test_post_data );
            $testId = $testController->addTestResults($test_data_request);
```

Comment: Great Solution! Someone like me will surely value your work when curl doesn't work at all. Kudos.

Answer (score 0):

You've not provided enough information, but i think, the problem will be one or more of the following:

- The WebServer `http://127.0.0.1:8000` is not running
- The script located on `http://127.0.0.1:8000/tests/add/results` is running too long and the request timeouts before it is completed
- The requested path is returning redirect headers and creates an infinite loop
- The response is too big to finish the data transfer in thirty seconds (very wierd if on localhost)

Try some more debugging and provide more information on this, so we may help you.

---

PS: Firstly i would try to catch the headers (`curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);`) and print out the response (`var_dump($response);`) - or save it to some file :)

Comment: I can use postman and send the post and it works fine. Like i mentioned the CURL call itself seems to execute only after the timeout limit passes so if i put 10 seconds itll execute after 10 seconds

Comment: @Yeak Can you put the response headers to the original question? (as an edit)